# Como coloca cinco números em ordem crescente e descente usando portugol? [closed]

Tags: algoritmo, lógica, portugol, portugol-studio

Crie um algoritmo onde o usuário entrará com 5 números inteiros e depois escreva os números em ordem crescente e decrescente.

Essa é uma atividade da escola que meu professor passou, não estou sabendo como fazer. Alguém poderia me explicar?

Só cheguei na parte de pedir ao usuário que informe os números

```html
programa {
  funcao inicio() {
    inteiro n1, n2, n3, n4, n5

    escreva("Informe o número 1: ")
    leia(n1)
    escreva("Informe o número 2: ")
    leia(n2)
    escreva("Informe o número 3: ")
    leia(n3)
    escreva("Informe o número 4: ")
    leia(n4)
    escreva("Informe o número 5: ")
    leia(n5)

    
  }
}
```

Comment: Dificilmente alguém irá fazer a tarefa por ti aqui, tente postar o código que tentou fazer com os laços de repetição

Comment: Não estou pedindo para que façam a resposta por mim, eu não mandei o código porque não o fiz, não estou entendendo por onde começar.

Comment: Digamos que eu digitei na seguinte ordem: 5,3,1,7,9. Tu vai ter que salvar esses numeros e fazer um compara entre eles para exibir na ordem crescente: 1,3,5,7,9 e de na ordem decrescente: 9,7,5,4,3,1